# takes null-terminate ascii string, returns int value

Tags: c, string

I'm making two functions.

The functions are main and stringToInt.

In main function has two arguments (int argc, char *argv[]). And it takes arguments from command line. 
Ex) `./a.out 1 2 3 4`

And second function, I believe to be one argument which is char *argv[].

How would I code that takes null-terminate ASCII string and returns into value in stringToInt function.

Any help/example would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show us what you tried before ? You just want to recode an atoi() as I understood, am I right ?

Comment: @NicolasCharvozKurzawa yes, I want to recode atoi().

Comment: Is it a school project or just for fun ?

Comment: @NicolasCharvozKurzawa nothing relates to school project.

Comment: It would seem that a Google search for "atoi source code" answers your question. This Google thing is gonna get big, I tell ya!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int strToInt(char *str){
    int total = 0;
    while(*str)
        total = total * 10 + (*str++ - '0');
    return total;
}
```

How this works:

it starts looping over each character, converting it to integer (via ascii):

so 
`'1' - '0' = 1`
`'2' - '0' = 2` and so on

The function:

1. the function checks if the string passed to it is not null or empty.
2. loops character by character, converting it to an integer from `char` form.
3. multiplies `total` by `10` each time it passes to next character that is not NULL terminator
4. returns the value if NULL is reached.

so when lets say "123" is passed to `strToInt()`

LOOP1: 
  `'1'` is encountered, `total=0`
  `'1'` is converted to number 1 by formula: `'1' - '0'`
  `total` is now `total * 10 + 1` = `0 + 1` = `1`

LOOP2:
  `'2'` is encountered,`total = 1`
  `'2'` is now converted to number 2 by formula: `'2' - '0'`
  `total` is now `total * 10 + 2` = `10 + 2` = `12`.

LOOP3:
   `'3'` is encountered, `total = 12`
   `'3'` is now converted to number 3 by formula: `'3' - '0'`
   `total` is now `total * 10 + 3` = `12*10 + 3` = `123`.

LOOP4:
   NULL is encountered, and the function returns `total` = 123.

Comment: I would suggest some explanation to the OP. (S)he seems to really need it! :)

Comment: Can you explain little bit more please

Comment: @user4031074 yes, please see post

Comment: This does not work for anything longer than a 1 digit number.

Comment: @Aniket your newly edited version is better, but doesn't handle negative numners.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this :

```
int             my_get_nbr(char *str)
{
  int           res;

  if (*str == '-')
    return (-my_get_nbr(str + 1));
  if (*str == '+')
    return (my_get_nbr(str + 1));
  res = 0;
  while (*str)
    {
      res = res * 10;
      res = res + *str - '0';
      str = str + 1;
    }
  return (res);
}
```

Comment: that's some crazy indentation

Comment: @zoska Yeah there's a code norm in my school .. Epitech if you want to know, not my fault haha

Comment: @Medinoc For beginners I think x = x + y is more readable .. And I did this code a year ago when I was learning C !